# Linker error with DirectX C++

Tags: c++, linker, directx, linker-errors

I'm working on a Direct X11 project, and i am trying to draw a rectangle in the window i generated (the whole window  directX initialization did work fine, since it compiled correctly before). 
For this, i included the following headers :

```
#include "CommonStates.h"
#include "SpriteBatch.h"
```

I added the link of these headers to the C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories, and i think it did find it since i have no errors about including it.

After, i tried to compile my project. The following lines caused some linker errors :

```
RECT *try1 = new RECT();
try1->bottom = 0; try1->left = 0; try1->right = 50; try1->bottom = 50;

CommonStates states(d3dDevice);
sprites->Begin(SpriteSortMode_Deferred, states.NonPremultiplied());
sprites->Draw(textureRV, XMFLOAT2(50, 50), try1, Colors::Black);
sprites->End();
```

Errors :

```
1>Framework.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall DirectX::CommonStates::CommonStates(struct ID3D11Device *)" (??0CommonStates@DirectX@@QAE@PAUID3D11Device@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Framework::Draw2(unsigned long *)" (?Draw2@Framework@@QAEXPAK@Z)
1>Framework.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall DirectX::CommonStates::~CommonStates(void)" (??1CommonStates@DirectX@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Framework::Draw2(unsigned long *)" (?Draw2@Framework@@QAEXPAK@Z)
1>Framework.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct ID3D11BlendState * __cdecl DirectX::CommonStates::NonPremultiplied(void)const " (?NonPremultiplied@CommonStates@DirectX@@QBAPAUID3D11BlendState@@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Framework::Draw2(unsigned long *)" (?Draw2@Framework@@QAEXPAK@Z)
1>Framework.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __vectorcall DirectX::SpriteBatch::Begin(enum DirectX::SpriteSortMode,struct ID3D11BlendState *,struct ID3D11SamplerState *,struct ID3D11DepthStencilState *,struct ID3D11RasterizerState *,class std::function<void __cdecl(void)>,struct DirectX::XMMATRIX)" (?Begin@SpriteBatch@DirectX@@QAQXW4SpriteSortMode@2@PAUID3D11BlendState@@PAUID3D11SamplerState@@PAUID3D11DepthStencilState@@PAUID3D11RasterizerState@@V?$function@$$A6AXXZ@std@@UXMMATRIX@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Framework::Draw2(unsigned long *)" (?Draw2@Framework@@QAEXPAK@Z)
1>Framework.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl DirectX::SpriteBatch::End(void)" (?End@SpriteBatch@DirectX@@QAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Framework::Draw2(unsigned long *)" (?Draw2@Framework@@QAEXPAK@Z)
1>Framework.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __vectorcall DirectX::SpriteBatch::Draw(struct ID3D11ShaderResourceView *,struct DirectX::XMFLOAT2 const &,union __m128)" (?Draw@SpriteBatch@DirectX@@QAQXPAUID3D11ShaderResourceView@@ABUXMFLOAT2@2@T__m128@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Framework::Draw2(unsigned long *)" (?Draw2@Framework@@QAEXPAK@Z)
1>Framework.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct DirectX::XMMATRIX const DirectX::SpriteBatch::MatrixIdentity" (?MatrixIdentity@SpriteBatch@DirectX@@0UXMMATRIX@2@B)
```

I figured these are some linker errors, so i added the path of the DirectXTK.lib file to Linker>General>Additional Dependencies. I did not find the CommonStates.lib nor the SpriteBatch.lib files though, even if i compiled the DirectXTK-master project, the only lib generated is DirectXTK.lib.

Hence, i added DirectXTK.lib to the Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies.
But then, i still the following errors :

```
1>DirectXTK.lib(CommonStates.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AddForceMessage.obj
1>DirectXTK.lib(CommonStates.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AddForceMessage.obj
1>DirectXTK.lib(SpriteBatch.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AddForceMessage.obj
1>DirectXTK.lib(SpriteBatch.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AddForceMessage.obj
1>DirectXTK.lib(pch.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AddForceMessage.obj
1>DirectXTK.lib(pch.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AddForceMessage.obj
1>DirectXTK.lib(VertexTypes.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AddForceMessage.obj
1>DirectXTK.lib(VertexTypes.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AddForceMessage.obj
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

So I really do not understand what it means, could you please tell me what i did wrong and what i should do to make it work please ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You're linking Debug libraries with a Release build, or Release libraries with a Debug build. Make sure you link the proper ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL'
> ```

This means the library you're linking to was built in a different configuration (Debug or Release) than the one used to build your current program.

Steps to fix:

1. Build the library **both** in Debug and in Release. You will get a `DirectXTK.lib` file for each of those (in different directories).
2. In your main program, choose Debug as the build configuration, go to Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies and add the Debug `DirectXTK.lib` file you just built. Make sure you add the directory where the `DirectXTK.lib` file is to VC++ Directories>Library Directories.
3. Repeat step 2 for Release mode. Make sure you're changing these configuration properties only for one configuration at time.

Now whenever you'll build your program in Debug mode, it will be linked to the Debug library, and same for Release.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It succeeded ! I had to precise the path of the used library in Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies to be sure it was using the good .lib file (so in debug mode, it was : $(ProjectDir)DirectXTK-master\Bin\Desktop_2015\Win32\Debug\DirectXTK.lib )  Thank you so very much Banex !! :)